# Zend or Apache is replacing my src value with data:image

Tags: apache, caching, zend-framework

I am working on a web site that I worked heavily on a couple of years ago but only maintained since. It was recently migrated to another server. The new server uses ZendFramework version 1.12.20 on Apache (httpd=2.4.6-88.el7.x86_64).

There seems to be a weird bug where instead of using the URL of an image, it sends data:image content. Unfortunately the data:image is of an old image icon instead of the replacement icon. If I go directly to the URL of the image, it also still shows the old image. So it seems like a caching problem.

I've tried clearing the web browser cache and restarting the web server. There are no image files in /usr/local/zend/library/Zend/Cache and /usr/share/php/Zend/Cache. What will clear the Zend or Apache cache?